# use a model in my rails header partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, model, partial-views

I have contest model which I want to use in my _header partial.

The header partial is located in an elements folder but there is no elements model.

I want my header to display all the contests in the menu.

**How can I best handle this? Create a elements model or move the _header partial to my Contest folder and add it there to the controller?**

Answer (score 0):

Simply spoken a model is mostly holding some data which is persited in the database. To insert content in the header while rendering specific views you can stick with [content_for](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method). Basic idea: while rendering a view you can pass your object / model via locals from the controller into your view template which passes it further via content_for to render the header specifically.

Comment: So if I understand this right I should put the content for method in my contests helper and then call it in my header?

Comment: The problem is I want my header to be the same in all my views, also the ones not from the contest model.